# Any way to automatically reload a file selected from "InputFile" through Filereader?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display a CSV file into an HTML table.
I have it set up so that you can pick the CSV and it will successfully show in HTML format.

Is there anyway to refresh this so that if the selected file Changes, the HTML format will change with it (Without user input re-selected the file.

Code and Table are below. But basically I would like it so that if the population of New York changed in the table, that the HTML table is automatically updated as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<input type="file" id="fileUpload" onchange="Upload()"/>
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" onclick="Upload()" />

<hr />
<div id="dvCSV">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function Upload() {
        var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
        if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var table = document.createElement("table");
                    var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                        if (cells.length > 1) {
                            var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                            for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                                var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                                cell.innerHTML = cells[j];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    var dvCSV = document.getElementById("dvCSV");
                    dvCSV.innerHTML = "";
                    dvCSV.appendChild(table);
               } 
                reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0]);
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            }
        } 
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  Upload();
  setInterval(function(){ Upload(); }, 10000);
</script>

</html>
```

| rank | place | population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New York | 8175133 |
| 2 | Los Angeles | 3792621 |
| 3 | Chicago | 2695598 |

Comment: Once user uploads a file, it is a copy of that file that the browser refers to, not the original. So unless you also write a server side program that reads files directly from file system, and watches for changes, I don't think its possible.

Comment: thank you for the feedback Anurag, appreciate it.